# Command on new line

Tags: windows, command-line, node.js

I have the following command: `cd ../../game ^ electron src` that I need to run.

Which basically means step up two folders from our current directory then into the game folder and call electron on the src folder.

However it sees the `electron src` command as part of the `cd` command... and gives the error `can't find the path specified`

How can I break it up? so put the `electron src` AFTER the `cd` command.

This command gets executed inside a NodeJS application like:

`exec('cd ../../game ^ electron src', function(...`

As you can see I have tried the `^` to break it up but that doesn't seem to solve the problem... I have tried the same code in a Windows command prompt and it happens there so it's not because of the way NodeJS executes it.

Comment: Can you just give it the full path? `C:/folder/folder/game electron src`

Comment: No because it still says it can't find the path specified.

Comment: @CloseVoter, questions about using commands in the windows command line or batch files are on topic here.

Comment: @Cameron, please could you tag this Windows or Unix/Mac/Linux, and say clearly in the question which OS you're on? It makes a significant difference to the answer on command-line questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How do I run one command then run another?

Use the following command:

```
cd ../../game & electron src
```

The `&` means run the first command then run the second.

If you think the first command might fail then use `&&` instead.

---

#### What is the syntax for command redirection?

- `command > filename`        Redirect command output to a file
- `command >> filename`       APPEND into a file
- `command < filename`        Type a text file and pass the text to command
- `commandA  |  commandB`     Pipe the output from commandA into commandB
- `commandA &  commandB`      Run commandA and then run commandB
- `commandA && commandB`      Run commandA, if it succeeds then run commandB
- `commandA || commandB`      Run commandA, if it fails then run commandB

Source [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

---

#### Further reading

[An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) is an excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.

Comment: This works fine in the command prompt but for some reason in NodeJs it just forgets the cd immediately after the & and calls electron in the current directory we are in...

Comment: Does the same thing... calls electron in the same directory we are running the script inside...

Comment: Neither really, so I have just called the exe directly using a different method. Seems that the electron command has issues with the cd when used inside NodeJS. Accepted answer as the `&` was the best solution outside of Node :P